# Doxygen brief description from within macro expansion

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider following C++ declaration macro:

```
#define DECLARE_OBJECT_HANDLE(x) \
typedef struct x##HandleTag *x##Handle; \
typedef struct x##Handle *P##x##Handle
```

I want to mark my second pointer declaration with some doxygen comments. Ideally I would like the second handle to have reference to the first one with only brief description that says it is a pointer to this type.

I have changed my macro:

```
#define DECLARE_OBJECT_HANDLE(x) \
typedef struct x##HandleTag *x##Handle; \
/**
* \brief Pointer to x##Handle.
*/ \
typedef struct x##Handle *P##x##Handle
```

I was really surprised, when I found out that it's working somehow!
Unfortunately, there is an extra section for each typefef with some weird character:

[image]

I really really dislike the bottom section, because I have nothing more to say about it. Is this a bug in doxygen, that it produces extra section when I only asked for brief description?

**Is there a way how to prevent it**?

PS: I am using doxygen version 1.8.12 on Window 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: That weird character is a bullet point from an unordered list. Have you tried omitting the `*` in front of the `\brief` doxycommand?

Comment: @Torbjörn Thank you, it worked! Do you have an explanation, why it happens or is it just a wild guess? I don't have much experience with doxygen

Comment: That was an educated guess, as the asterisk at the beginning of a line is indicating an unordered list in Markdown. You could investigate whether that's actually the case when you turn off Markdown support in your Doxyfile. You might consider reporting a bug to the Doxygen devs then.

Comment: When I turn off the markdown support there is no longer a bullet, but an asterisk. Anyway, when I use the same syntax anywhere else than in comment I get correct behavior. I didn't even know, that doxycommand is supposed to be in the first line. Do you still think it's worth reporting?

Comment: There is a space missing before the asterisks, in order to be aligned with the comment opening. Doxygen should expect that space to recognize this comment style.

Comment: What is the weird character you are talking about ?

Comment: You posted some defines but it doesn't look like the ones to generate the documentation. Please post the code you used to generate the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the weird character I was referring to is a **bullet point from an unordered list**.

I asked this question on doxygen development list, but no-one has replied.

The solution:

> omit the `*` in front of the `\brief` doxycommand

PS: The original code is working everywhere outside macro expansion.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit hard for doxygen to get the right flow in case of mixing defines, comment and typedefs. Maybe the following gives some hints / ideas (as it is not 100% clear what you try to achieve):

```
/**  Handle */
#define HT(x) \
typedef struct x##HandleTag *x##Handle

/** Pointer to #HT(x) */
#define PHT(x) \
typedef struct x##Handle *P##x##Handle

/** Doing both */
#define DECLARE_OBJECT_HANDLE(x) \
HT(x); \
PHT(x)
```

Comment: I was trying to make your idea working, but the nested macros didn't work for me. I wanted to declare both opaque pointer to some structure and at the same time declare a pointer to it, that has only a brief description. However, there was more than a brief description (the bullet for list) for unknown reason. The reason seem to be, that I didn't put the \brief keyword on the first line, but there was an extra asterisk, which was interpreted as a start of the list. This is difference between macros and regular code, where I can put \brief command on separate line with correct behavior.